# How to eliminate space between dt and dd?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to eliminate the space between dt and dd elements.

I have set all the margins and padding between the two elements to 0. However, the space persists.

I added a background for each (green is dt, tan is dd) and there is clearly a blank space in the middle.

[image]

How can I eliminate that space completely or control its height?

To clarify, I mean the space *beneath* the dt elements and *above* the dd elements. I would like a space after the dd since each dt and dd is grouped together, and I can accomplish that just fine by using `padding-bottom: 10px;`

```css
    * {
   margin: 0;
    }
    body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    } 

   
dt,
dd {
  display: block;
}
dt {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #98fb98;
}

dd {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #f6f0e8;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>HTML</dt>
  <dd><em>HyperText Markup Language</em> describes the structure of the page and its contents.</dd>
  <dt>CSS</dt>
  <dd><em>Cascading Style Sheets</em> describes how a site looks and even to some extent how it responds to certain events.</dd>
  <dt>JavaScript</dt>
  <dd>JavaScript is the programming language used to define the logic and function of a site beyond simple look and feel. Any computation or "thinking" is done using JavaScript.</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: could you share a link? What does the web inspector say? it could be possibile that the inner elements have a margin applied?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - **Unable to replicate** - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NOEqWV

Comment: I'cant reproduce the problem, Can we see the markup ?

Comment: What do you have _inside_ your `dd`? Some element like a `p` that has default margins applied via the browser stylesheet maybe …?

Comment: @misorude As you can see by my example, just text. No other elements are inside the dd elements.

Comment: Turns out I had `#main * {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}` in my style.css which was the culprit. My style was not overriding it automatically. Adding `!important` to the style took care of it. Issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dt, dd{
    margin-block-start: 0px;
    margin-block-end: 0em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change anything for me either

Comment: Your code snippet is showing it run as you are asking, and I got it to run as you wanted as well.  I suggest going into dev tools(ctrl+shift+i) and check what css properties are being applied to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
dt, dd {
            display: block;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        dt {
            font-weight: 500;
            clear: both;
            background-color: #98fb98;
        }
        dd {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            background-color: #f6f0e8;
        }   
</style>


<dd>This is dd</dd>
<dt>This is dt</dt>
<dd>This is dd</dd>
<dt>This is dt</dt>
<dd>This is dd</dd>
<dt>This is dt</dt>
<dd>This is dd</dd>
<dt>This is dt</dt>
```

Comment: This did not change anything for me. Looks exactly the same as before

Answer (score -3):

reset css by adding this css

```
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it before you posted it?

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what the problem is: and what if the user has an `!important` margin elsewhere? why does he should reset all those properties for every element even if he doesn't need to? This approach is potentially harmful

Comment: it's not harmful approach